# unable to import a js file in vue native

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-component, vue-native

as you can see I tried to import the js from `src/store`

I tried the following path but none of them working.

`./store/member.module`

`/@store/member.module`

`member.module`

Previously I used `/@store/member.module` for my others Vue project but somehow it is not working in vue native

[image]

Comment: did you try out `@store/member.module`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes, i tried, but still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `src`

```
./src/store/member.module
```

I suggest to create a folder named `member` with a js file in it `module.js`. Better avoid these dot notation names